# Mac OSX prompt git branch aware

Tags: macos, git, bash, command-prompt

Ive been playing with the .profile file in my home directory, in order to show the git branch on the prompt and also to show the rvm gemset and python virtual env Im currently in... mostly all works fine, the problem that I'm having is that in order to show the branch in a different color depending on the state of the branch I have to do source ~/.profile every time, also I have to do the same in order to show the python virtualenv in CYAN.

Theres gotta be a way or something that Im missing so that I dont have to run source ~/.profile every time I go into a different folder so that the branch color is based on the status.

Heres my .profile

https://gist.github.com/3628788

Thanks for your help figuring this out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the PROMPT_COMMAND variable to define a function that sets your `PS1` after every command. Put this at the bottom of your .profile file in place of the assignment to `PS1`:

```
prompt_cmd () {
    PS1="${PYTHON_VIRTUALENV}$PURPLE\$(set_rvm_prompt)$NO_COLOUR\u@\h:[\W]${B_STATE}\$(parse_git_branch)$NO_COLOUR\$ "
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_cmd
```

Now, just before displaying your prompt, `bash` will execute the function `prompt_cmd`, updating `PS1` for the most recent information according to `PYTHON_VIRTUALENV`, `set_rvm_prompt()`, and `parse_git_branch()`.

Comment: I had to add set_rvm_prompt and parse_git_branch to prompt_cmd, and now works like a charm!... Heres the updated file https://gist.github.com/3354613